# Capturar un Alert con WebView2

Tags: c#, wpf, webview2

Tengo un control de WebView2 dentro de una aplicación WPF en C# y quiero capturar cuando se dispare un Alert, y filtrar por el contenido del Alert.

He intentado capturarlo con el evento:

```
public event EventHandler<Microsoft.Web.WebView2.Core.CoreWebView2WebMessageReceivedEventArgs>
```

Pero no dispara el evento, hay alguna manera inyectando un script de JavaScript para poder capturarlos? Hay algún evento especifico para ello?.

Gracias y un saludo